# Persistent SWT shell window positions

Tags: eclipse, shell, swt

I have code similar to what the example below does that allows me to have a shell open in a different location. What I need to do is track the window position if it's moved and save those positions for the next time that window is opened. Any suggestions?

```
 public StartupSplashShell(Display display)
 {
     shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM);
     setupShell();  // place components in the main avoCADo shell
     shell.setText("avoCADo");
     shell.setBackgroundImage(ImageUtils.getIcon("./avoCADo-Splash.jpg", 
     360, 298));
     shell.setSize(360, 298);   //TODO: set intial size to last known size
     Rectangle b = display.getBounds();
     int xPos = Math.max(0, (b.width-360)/2);
     int yPos = Math.max(0, (b.height-298)/2);
     shell.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
     shell.setImage(ImageUtils.getIcon("./avoCADo.png", 32, 32));
     shell.open();
}
```

Comment: So is this the code that you are having the problem with?

Comment: Is this just a plain SWT application or part of an Eclipse RCP or ...?

Answer (score 3):

Inject `IEclipsePreferences` in your exit application handler and save the bounds in eclipse preferences, if you are working on Eclipse Plugin.

```
@Inject
@Preference
private IEclipsePreferences preferences;
```

If your application is standalone SWT application then you can use file (properies for example) or database to persist the bounds of the shell

```
mainShell.getBounds() // serialize it in String
preferences.put("SHELL_BOUNDS", boundStr);
```

Again inject preferences when your application starts and retrieve the bounds from preferences

```
bounds = preferences.get("SHELL_BOUNDS", "");
```

Then you can set location and size of shell

```
mainShell.setLocation(xAxis, yAxis);
mainShell.setSize(width, height);
```

Comment: This assumes an Eclipse plug-in (and something which is injected), the question tags just say SWT.

Comment: Yes its my mistake in understanding. For storing purpose even properties can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a plain SWT application you can use the `SWT.Move` listener to be told each time the shell moves:

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Move, event ->
  { 
    Point location = shell.getLocation();
    ....
  });
```

Or you can use a `SWT.Close` listener to just listen for the shell closing:

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Close, event ->
  { 
    Point location = shell.getLocation();
    ....
  });
```

If you want to save the location between runs of the application you would have to save the location in something like a `Properties` file.

Comment: Remember to check if the position is still on-screen when restoring. Depending on the monitor setup, it might not.